# Get URL of a specific file

Tags: plugins, themes

I have a file that can either be included in a plugin, or in a theme. What's the best way to get the URL of the file's folder (from within the file)?

Edit:

I'm now using this for now

```
home_url( '/' . str_replace( ABSPATH, "", dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

Let me know if there's any problem with this / there's a better way.

Comment: Do you know the exact location within the **Plugin** where the file would be located?

Comment: What does this file do? There might be a better way ... And do you need the full URL or to just know the location?

Comment: @ChipBennett Nope, I don't know anything about the relative location of the file in either the plugin or the theme.

Comment: @EAMann It's an Options page generator/helper, that could either be used by a plugin or a theme.

Comment: Since this is not quite trivial task for generic case, could you add some details how youe envision your library will be used and included in third party code?

Answer (score 4):

See [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories).

```
plugins_url( 'filename', __FILE__ );
```

… returns the full URI to the file in your plugin. For themes you use:

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/file';
```

Comment: The problem is, that I don't know if it's included in a plugin _or_ a theme. Also, I don't know the path of the file, so your stylesheet example won't work. Neither do I know the name of the plugin. It's a utility library.

Comment: I write my own library right now, and it is a plugin. Themes and other plugins may use it, but the library is kept separate. Otherwise there would be no way to create a reliable file access – as you can see. :P

Answer (score 4):

Using ABSPATH and `home_url()` might not work if the wp installation is in a different directory to the url it is displayed at. You should test that out.

My thought is using the content directory as a place to do the replacement might be more robust as you can pass the resulting path into `content_url()` which accounts for where the WP installation is:

```
function get_file_url( $file = __FILE__ ) {
    $file_path = str_replace( "\\", "/", str_replace( str_replace( "/", "\\", WP_CONTENT_DIR ), "", $file ) );
    if ( $file_path )
        return content_url( $file_path );
    return false;
}
```

This could be simplified for unix only but the above supports windows too.

Comment: Note that it's not guaranteed that plugin/theme is actually inside content dir. They can be easily located elsewhere.

Comment: Ah good point. Still, 80/20 ;)

Comment: @Rarst What exactly are you referring too?

Comment: @kaiser theme and plugin directories can be configured, residing inside of `wp-content` is merely default setting for them.

Comment: @Rarst Ah, sry. Missread. Thought it was `WP_PLUGIN_DIR`.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you write both case and check which one is actually pointing to a real file:

```
function dogbert_library_get_file_path($filename) {
    // As you might put your file in a folder, just configure this path
    $path_to_file = "files/" .$filename;

    // get_theme_root() doesn't give trailing slash
    $themeFile = get_theme_root() ."/" .get_current_theme() ."/" .$path_to_file;
    // plugin_dir_path does give trailing slash
    $pluginFile = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) .$path_to_file ;

    // As we are at filesystem layer, we can use file_exists to check
    if(file_exists($themeFile)){
        return $themeFile;
    } else if(file_exists($pluginFile)) {
        return $pluginFile;
    } else {
        // Return empty as a fallback...
       return "";
    }
}
```

That's the best option I would see.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a filter.

In your file, somewhere at the very beginning, include something along the lines of:

```
add_filter( 'wpa45165_resource_url', 'wpa45165_resource_url_finder' );
function wpa45165_resource_url_finder( $url ) {
    $url = /* Some code to generate the url from WP_SITEURL and dirname() */;

    return $url;
}
```

Then, in the code that needs to reference the file, apply the filter to an empty string:

```
$include_url = apply_filters( 'wpa45165_resource_url', '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

```php
$themes_search_index = strpos(__FILE__,'wp-content/themes');
$plugins_search_index = strpos(__FILE__,'wp-content/plugins');
$url_postfix_prospect = dirname(__FILE__);

if( $themes_search_index !== false ){
    $url_postfix_index = strpos($url_postfix_prospect,'wp-content/themes');
} elseif( $plugins_search_index !== false ) {
    $url_postfix_index = strpos($url_postfix_prospect,'wp-content/plugins');
}

$url_prefix = get_site_url();
$url_postfix = substr($url_postfix_prospect, $url_postfix_index);
$lib_path_url = $url_prefix .'/'. $url_postfix;

echo $lib_path_url;
```

**Given the file path...**

```
/var/www/html/example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/lib/an-awesome-library/autoload.php
```

**Results to...**

```
http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/lib/an-awesome-library
```

### Problem

Building a *plug-and-play* library for wordpress that can either be "*included*" inside a theme or plugin can be difficult. Wordpress has **no pre-defined function** for getting the URL of that file.

### Solution

Treat plugins and themes separately.

#### Step 1. Check whether included inside theme or plugin

```php
/**
 * Contains numeric values if the respective strings are found,
 * Contains boolean `false` if the string is not found
 */
$themes_search_index = strpos(__FILE__,'wp-content/themes');
$plugins_search_index = strpos(__FILE__,'wp-content/plugins');
```

#### Step 2a. If inside a theme

```php
$url_postfix_prospect = dirname(__FILE__);

$url_postfix_index = strpos($url_postfix_prospect,'wp-content/themes');
$url_prefix = get_site_url();
$url_postfix = substr($url_postfix_prospect, $url_postfix_index);
$lib_path_url = $url_prefix .'/'. $url_postfix;

echo $lib_path_url;
```

#### Step 2b. If inside a plugin

```php
$url_postfix_prospect = dirname(__FILE__);

$url_postfix_index = strpos($url_postfix_prospect,'wp-content/plugins');
$url_prefix = get_site_url();
$url_postfix = substr($url_postfix_prospect, $url_postfix_index);
$lib_path_url = $url_prefix .'/'. $url_postfix;

echo $lib_path_url;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: An [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) is not the local path.